# How to correctly map a JSON structure to an object?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

How to correctly map the following structure to an object
There is JSON:

```json
{"store": [{
      "id":"100",
      "products": {
         "prod1":["price","quantity"],   //Maximum 2 elements
         "prod2":["price","quantity"],   //Maximum 2 elements
         "prod3":["price","quantity"]    //Maximum 2 elements
         //There may be many (known or not..prod4, prod5....)
        }}]}
```

Classes:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Store {

    @JsonProperty("store")
    private Set<Stores> stores;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Stores {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("products")
    private Set<Products> productsSet;
}    

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Products {
    ??????
}
```

How do I need to write in class Products?

Mapper:

```java
//omit exceptions and other code
public Store toStoreFromJson(String str) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(str, Store.class);

}
```

Comment: Since the keys for the products seem to be arbitrary I'd say you need a `Map<String, Product>`. To map this I'd suggest you put it into `Stores` using the name `products` (and remove `productsSet` which doesn't make sense here - a set would be mapped to a JSON array and your JSON doesn't have an array at that property).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your products are dynamic, and can be any number of them. So you are not dealing with a collection (Set or List), but more with a dictionary, like a Map.

This solution might not be the desired (will need an adapter to desired model):

```
class Stores {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("products")
    private Products productsSet;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class Products extends LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> {
}
```

And the test:

```
   Store store = mapper.readValue("{\"store\": ....", Store.class);

    assertEquals(1, store.stores.size());

    Products product = store.getStores().stream().map(Stores::getProductsSet).findFirst().orElseThrow();
    product.forEach((name, prices) -> {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + Arrays.toString(prices));
    });
```

Will print:

```
prod1: [price, quantity]
prod2: [price, quantity]
prod3: [price, quantity]
```

======================================================================

Better approach would be to use a collection to represent products:

```
{
  "store": [
    {
      "id": "100",
      "products": [
        {"name": "prod1", "prices": ["price","quantity"]},
        {"name": "prod2", "prices": ["price","quantity"]},
        {"name": "prod3", "prices": ["price","quantity"]}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The only downside of this approach would be the possibility of duplicates. But it depends if you can change the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

It worked

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Stores {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("products")
    private Map<String, T> productsSet;
}
```